# why the websocat shows websocat: WebSocketError: I/O failure when using localhost

Tags: websocket, terminal

Today I want to test the websocket in docker alpine container using websocat 1.11.0. when I using the localhost, shows error like this:

```
/home/node/app # websocat ws://localhost:1234
websocat: WebSocketError: I/O failure
websocat: error running
```

when I using the 127.0.0.1, seem no error output:

```
/home/node/app # websocat ws://127.0.0.1:1234
```

why did this happen? Am I missing something?